# How to Display Successful and Failed Data in Laravel Maatwebsites Import

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In my Laravel-5.8 using Maatwebsites-3.1, I am trying to update Employee Leaves into MySQL database through MS Excel.

Controller

```
public function import(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:xlsx,xls',
    ]);
  $path1 = $request->file('file')->store('temp'); 
 $path=storage_path('app').'/'.$path1;  

    try{

        Excel::import(new LeavesImport, $path);         
        
    } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
        $failures = $e->failures();
        Log::error($e);
        $errormessage = "";
        
     foreach ($failures as $failure) {
         $errormess = "";
         foreach($failure->errors() as $error)
         {
             $errormess = $errormess.$error;
         }
         $errormessage = $errormessage." ,\n At Row ".$failure->row().", ".$errormess."<br>";
     }
         Session::flash('error', $errormessage);
         return back();            
    }catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
    {
        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
        if($errorCode == 1062){
        Log::error($e);
        DB::rollback();
        Session::flash('error', 'You have a duplicate entry problem!');
        }
        return back();
    }        
    Session::flash('success', 'Leave Records Imported Successfully');
    return redirect()->back;        
}
```

Below is the code for the data to be imported from the MS Excel Sheet
Import

```
class FirstLeaveSheetImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithBatchInserts, WithValidation
{
    protected $staffid, $leavetype, $commencementdate, $resumptiondate;
    private $errors = []; // array to accumulate errors
    use Importable;

        return new HrLeaveRequest([
            'employee_id'                       => $this->getStaffId(),
            'leave_type_id'                     => $this->getLeaveType(),
            'commencement_date'                 => $this->transformDate($row['commencement_date']),
            'resumption_date'                   => $this->transformDate($row['resumption_date']),
            'no_of_days'                        => $row['leave_days'],  
        ]);        

    }

    public function getStaffId(){
        if(!empty($this->staffid)){

            return HrEmployee::where('employee_code',$this->staffid)->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id)->pluck('id')->first();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public function getLeaveType(){
        if(!empty($this->leavetype) || !$this->leavetype){

            return HrLeaveType::where('leave_type_name',$this->leavetype)->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id)->pluck('id')->first();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }    

    // this function returns all validation errors after import:
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function transformDate($value, $format = 'Y-m-d')
    {
        try {
            return \Carbon\Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value));
        } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
            return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
        }
    } 

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 200;
    }    

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }      
}
```

I want to display:

1. The List Successful uploads
2. The list of failed uploads

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: does your code only accept one file upload?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond - Yes, You are correct

Comment: How did you solve that?